# Missing props in mapStateToProps

Tags: react-router, react-redux, react-apollo

### Version

4.1.1

### Steps to reproduce

This component is querying a db via GraphQL thanks to Apollo. It is a GraphQL container.
It uses `compose` from `react-apollo` library in order to use [multiple enhanchers](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api-graphql.html#compose) at the same time, in a readable way.

Example component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { graphql, compose, withApollo } from 'react-apollo';
import { myQuery } from './graphqlQuery';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { exampleProp } = this.props;
    return null;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  // I expect to see ownProps.exampleProp here but it is undefined
  console.log(ownProps.exampleProp);
}

export default compose(
  withApollo,
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  graphql(myQuery),
)(MyComponent);
```

### Expected Behavior

ownProps should contain the props passed to the component [as stated here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments)
like:

```
Object = {
  client: ApolloClient
  exampleProp: "propcontent",  // <-- this is going to be lost
  history: Object
  location: Object
  match: Object
  staticContext: undefined
  __proto__: Object
}
```

### Actual Behavior

instead ownProps contains only this:

```
Object = {
  client: ApolloClient
  history: Object
  location: Object
  match: Object
  staticContext: undefined
  __proto__: Object
}
```

All the props that the component should have had from parents and from GraphQL response are missing, including, in this case, `exampleProp`.

Comment: are you missing props from `graphql(myQuery)` or something higher up in the chain?

Comment: @azium I am missing both

Comment: well it wouldn't make sense for `grahql` props to exist in `mapStateToProps` because it's after `connect` in your compose function. that would be equivalent of passing props up to a parent somehow

Comment: @azium the problem is with normal props too, anyway the first time the component renders it has no graphql data in props but when the query is loaded then it has and mapStateToProps is fired again but without graphql data inside